# Using a NuGet Package Created with CPack in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, nuget, cpack

I am creating a NuGet package of a C++ CMake project using CPack.

```
cmake -S . -B build
cmake --build build --config Release
cd build
cpack -G NuGet -C 'Release'
```

I have defined several *cpack* variables, e.g.:

```
CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME
CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR
CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION
```

- The package is generated successfully. It contains an *include* and *lib* directory, just as the CMake's `install()` commands it to.
- I can add the NuGet package to my project in Visual Studio. The content gets installed.
- But the project doesn't find the headers and libs. I guess the meta data is missing in the package.

How do I add this info? Or am I missing something?

Comment: What is the structure of your package?

Comment: In the root folder there are _lib_, _bin_ and _include_ folders.
I have learned by now that Visual Studio is looking for a .targets file in a **build** directory. In this file you find the meta data I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meta info I was looking for can be found in a .targets file. See [here](https://github.com/NuGet/docs.microsoft.com-nuget/blob/main/docs/concepts/MSBuild-props-and-targets.md) for more info.

So I manually created such a file and added it with a cmake `install()` instruction, so cpack would include it in the NuGet package. Important: Visual Studio looks for it in a subdirectory called `build`, more specifically: `<nuget root>/build/**/<nuget name>.targets`. It looks something like this:

```
<Project>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalDependencies>
        $(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../lib/foo.lib;
  [...]
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
        $(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../include;
  [...]
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../bin/foo.dll">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  [...]
```

I mostly reverse engineered the syntax from random nuget packages. I'm not 100% happy with this solution. But it works.

Fee free to tell me more about it if you know anything :-)